# Apex Error: INVALID_FIELD, No fields provided in an external foreign key reference in entity: Account: []

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, error

I'm writing a test class for an Apex Trigger and I keep getting the error,

### "INVALID_FIELD, No fields provided in an external foreign key reference in entity: Account: []".

I have been trying to figure out how to get around this for some time, but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated greatly. My current test class is as such.

```
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = '001e000000dp7YiAAI'];
    Account account = new Account();

    if(accounts.size() > 0){
        account = accounts.get(0);
    }

    Opportunity opp1 = New Opportunity();
    opp1.Name = 'Opp 1';
    opp1.Account = account;
    opp1.CloseDate = System.today() + 1;
    opp1.StageName = 'Prospecting';
    opp1.Part__c = 'blah';
    insert opp1;
    System.debug('opp1 passed');

    Opportunity opp2 = New Opportunity();
    opp2.Name = 'Opp 2';
    opp2.Account = account;
    opp2.CloseDate = System.today() + 2;
    opp2.StageName = 'Prospecting';
    opp2.Part__c = 'bleh';
    insert opp2;
    System.debug('opp2 passed');

    Opportunity opp3 = New Opportunity();
    opp3.Name = 'Opp 3';
    opp3.Account = account;
    opp3.CloseDate = System.today() + 3;
    opp3.StageName = 'Prospecting';
    opp3.Part__c = 'blue';
    insert opp3;
    System.debug('opp3 passed');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

> opp1.Accountid = account.id

at the place of `opp1.Account = account`. Because Account holding a whole record.